# Test Entry Criteria for a User Story

Tags: application-software-testing

**Context** : A team working in agile , on an complex  Front end Application.

**Question**:How an team working in agile come up with a definition of common  guiding "entry criteria"  for testing to decide when user stories should be rejected right away when not meeting the basic conditions without performing any further testing.

Comment: Using [example mapping](https://cucumber.io/blog/example-mapping-introduction/) is a good technique as well.

Answer (score 2):

Agree on the basic conditions for criteria for all stories.

This 'meta' conversation needs to be had.  It doesn't arise of its own accord, not being related to a ticket.
This is where leadership (at *all* levels) comes in.
Take charge of the situation, organize the meeting, get an agreement and then live by it.

The result of this is that future discussions can now be about the agreement, if its being met, if it needs to be changed, rather than trying to raise an issue about any given particular story.

Making something up, it could be:

- initial data state required
- user taking action
- expected result
- happy and sad cases

etc.

Make sure the **B**ehavior of users is the **D**river of the **D**evelopment process

See also https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories for Mike Cohn's take on user stories

Answer (score 2):

Basic entry condition for the user story testing could be:

- clear description
- status that is declaring readiness from development prospective
- remaining team iteration capacity that is enough for story testing according to the estimations given on sprint planning
- a build that has been prepared by dev team with enabled unit tests where all the tests passed successfully

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are looking for [Definition of Ready](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/definition-of-ready/) if I understood the question correctly.

Usually the INVEST matrix is used for this:
A good user story should be:

- “I” ndependent (of all others)
- “N” egotiable (not a specific contract
  for features)
- “V” aluable (or vertical)
- “E” stimable (to a good
  approximation)
- “S” mall (so as to fit within an iteration)
- “T”estable (in principle, even if there isn’t a test for it yet)

There is also a good take on it by Vojtech Barta called [Parallel of Rally Dakar and Agile - rediscover of DoR & DoD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePZvuTm-cHY) where he gives examples on how to start the process of defining the DoR. DoR should not be set in stone but should evolve along with the team development process.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the application is complex then its complex for both the testers and the developer so i think all the team members should work as across functional so this may solve the complexity of user stories and facilitate to understand user stories .